# html dom target elements

Tags: javascript, dom

i got problems with my memory game . 
I posted the html and js files.
In js file following codelines:

ListofOpenCards[0].target.className.removeClass(" open show");
  ListofOpenCards[1].target.className.removeClass(" open show");

which should remove class "open show" are throwing errors. I keep trying but cant find a solution. Why is that ?  Thank You

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">


<script>
    var cardList1 = ["fa-diamond","fa-diamond","fa-paper-plane-o","fa-paper-plane-o","fa-anchor","fa-anchor","fa-bolt",
                     "fa-bolt","fa-cube","fa-cube","fa-leaf","fa-leaf","fa-bicycle","fa-bicycle","fa-bomb","fa-bomb"];
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="score-panel">
            <ul class="stars">
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
            </ul>

            <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

            <div class="restart">
                <i class="fa fa-repeat" onclick="cardList1 = shuffle(cardList1); shuffleAlert()"></i>
            </div>
        </section>

        <ul class="deck">
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card match">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card match">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card open show">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick="createNewCardList(cardList1)">createNewCardList</button>
    <ul id="testCard69" class="deck1 testCardDisplay"> 
    </ul>
</body>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

/* my js file */

```
/*
 * Create a list that holds all of your cards
 */

var cardList2 = ["fa-diamond","fa-diamond","fa-diamond","fa-diamond","fa-paper","fa-paper","fa-anchor","fa-anchor","fa-bolt","fa-bolt","fa-cube","fa-cube","fa-leaf","fa-leaf","fa-bicycle","fa-bicycle","fa-bomb","fa-bomb"];


/*
 * Display the cards on the page
 *   - shuffle the list of cards using the provided "shuffle" method below
 *   - loop through each card and create its HTML
 *   - add each card's HTML to the page
 */
var displayCards = document.querySelector(".testCardDisplay");
/*displayCards.appendChild(cardList)*/

function createNewCardList(cardlist){

  var ulCreation = document.createElement('ul');
    ulCreation.className = "";

for(i=0; i < cardlist.length; i++ ){  
  var liCreation = document.createElement('li');
  liCreation.className = "card";
  /*liCreation.innerHTML = cardlist[i];  oldWorkingVersion*/
  /*liCreation.innerHTML = <i class="fa cardlist[i]"></i>;*/
    var iCreation = document.createElement('i');
    iCreation.className = "fa ";
    iCreation.className += cardlist[i];
    liCreation.append(iCreation);

    ulCreation.append(liCreation);
    ulCreation.className = "deck";
    }

  /*var ulDock = document.getElementsByClassName("testCardDisplay");*/
  var ulDock = document.getElementById("testCard69");
  ulDock.parentNode.replaceChild(ulCreation, ulDock);

};


// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}

function shuffleAlert() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Cards have been reshuffled"); }, 0);
}

/*
 * set up the event listener for a card. If a card is clicked:
 *  - display the card's symbol (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *  - add the card to a *list* of "open" cards (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *  - if the list already has another card, check to see if the two cards match
 *    + if the cards do match, lock the cards in the open position (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + if the cards do not match, remove the cards from the list and hide the card's symbol (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + increment the move counter and display it on the page (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + if all cards have matched, display a message with the final score (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 */

/*document.getElementsByClassName("fa").addEventListener("click",checkStatus);*/
var clickedCard = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
console.log(clickedCard.length+"pre")

var currentCard ;
let ListofOpenCardskids = [];
var ListofOpenCards = [];
var currentCounterVal =0;


var parentOfClick = document.querySelector(".deck");

parentOfClick.addEventListener("click", afterClick,false);

function afterClick(e){
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget){
    var clickedItem = e.target.children[0].className;
    console.log("clickedItem:" + clickedItem);
    console.log("eTargetClassname:" + e.target.className);
    /*e.target.className += " open show";*/
     displayCard(e);
    checkIfInList(e);
    counterWatch()
    console.log("counterwatch"+currentCounterVal);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}

function displayCard( currentCard){
  currentCard.target.className += " open show";
};

function checkIfInList(currentCard){

  ListofOpenCardskids.push(currentCard.target.children[0].className);  
  ListofOpenCards.push(currentCard.target.className);

  console.log("ListofOpenCardskids :"+ ListofOpenCardskids[0] + ListofOpenCardskids[1]);
  if (ListofOpenCardskids[0] === ListofOpenCardskids[1]){
    console.log("same two values in ListOfOpenCardArray")
    /*keepCardsopen;*/
    ListofOpenCardskids[0] += " match";
    ListofOpenCardskids[1] += " match";
    console.log(ListofOpenCardskids);
  }
  else
    {
      /*ListofOpenCards[0] -= " open show";
      ListofOpenCards[1] -= " open show";*/
      ListofOpenCards[0].target.className.removeClass(" open show");
      ListofOpenCards[1].target.className.removeClass(" open show");


      console.log("different values in ListOfOpenCardArray" + ListofOpenCardskids[0] + ListofOpenCardskids[1]);

     /* var coverCards = function( ListofOpenCards ){

  ListofOpenCards[0].target.className.removeClass(" open show");
  ListofOpenCards[1].target.className.removeClass(" open show");
}; */
    }

};


function counterWatch (){
  currentCounterVal += 1;
};

/*
function coverCards( ListofOpenCardsP ){

  ListofOpenCardsP[0].target.className.removeClass(" open show");
  ListofOpenCardsP[1].target.className.removeClass(" open show");
}; */
```

Comment: what errors does it throws?

Comment: `ListofOpenCards` is an array of classes(strings) not event objects

Comment: This is the error it throws:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
    at checkIfInList (index.js:122)
    at HTMLUListElement.afterClick (index.js:94)

Comment: @Musa thank you for your hint. It helped me alot